# how to validate before save stocktaking in magento 2 backend

Tags: magento, magento2

Help me ! 
i saved the qty successfully using ajax popup, but i want hide 2 button in popup

1. Close
2. Save

When you click the save button -> save
When you click the save Close-> not save

My jquery ajax

```
url = '/admin/stocktaking/index/save';
                // ajax
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type : 'post',
                    data: {sku: sku,qty: stocktaking},
                    showLoader: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (stocktaking >= 0) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                //popup success
                                var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.success).modal({
                                    modalClass: 'changelog',
                                    buttons: [{
                                        text: 'Close',
                                        click: function () {
                                            this.closeModal();
                                        }
                                    },{
                                        text: 'Save',
                                        click: function () {
                                            location.href = "/admin/stocktaking/index/save";
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                                popup.modal('openModal');
                                //end popup success
                                //popup error
                            } else if (data.error) {
                                var popup = $('<div class="themecafe-free-popup"/>').html(data.error).modal({
                                    modalClass: 'changelog',
                                    buttons: [{
                                        text: 'Close',
                                        click: function () {
                                            this.closeModal();
                                        }
                                    }]
                                });
                                popup.modal('openModal');
                                //end popup error
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following block of code and the buttons should disappear.

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Close',
        click: function () {
           this.closeModal();
        }
    },{
        text: 'Save',
        click: function () {
            location.href = "/admin/stocktaking/index/save";
            return false;
        }
    }]
```